# Equivalent command for windows : ./"XXX.exe" 2>&1 >> abc3.txt which is working in gitbash

Tags: java, command, prompt

The above given set of command is working and giving expected output in gitbash but i want the Equivalent command which will work in Windows environment.

Working command for gitbash : ./"XXX.exe" 2>&1 >> abc3.txt .

Comment: Please don't duplicate text just to work around the quality filter which presumably prompted you for more details. (I've removed the pointlessly-duplicated text.) Instead, improve the quality of the question by giving more details - what you're trying to achieve (rather than just "equivalent to this", what you've tried, what happened,  etc.

Comment: It's also completely unclear to me what this has to do with Java.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows command prompt you'll need to swap the redirections and switch path separator. This shows create (>) and append(>>):

```
.\blah.exe > abc.txt 2>&1
.\blah.exe >> abc.txt 2>&1
```

If you have the redirections the other way around, STDERR goes to the default of STDOUT whereas STDOUT goes to the file. Putting `2>&1` after `> abc.log` sends both to same file.

Comment: This command is creating the text file but it does not push any output content from cmd window to the created file. File created with 0 kb size.

Comment: Could you add example of the command line you used?